# How to convert JSON data with a list into an MariaDB SQL Insert statement that uses dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

Is it possible to store a JSON list field in MariaDB like the sample below using dynamic columns:

```
{
  "myfield": "value1",
  "myList": ["item1" , "item2", "item3"]
}
```

Comment: anything's possible, but there's no earthly reason why you'd want to do this

Comment: The JSON output comes from a third party system and I want to store it in a database in order to process it later.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question: how to convert the given JSON into an MariaDB SQL Insert statement that uses dynamic columns as described here. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/ You should specify which programming language you plan on using.

Comment: and define 'process'.

Comment: The json data will be processed from a python script or a Nodejs server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pity that MariaDB dynamic column doesn't support JSON array list natively although that's a fix for that and work better with INTEGERS but you can try to use a string.

```
 ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD COLUMN `dynamic_column` BLOB NULL DEFAULT
 NULL ;
```

You will store the array list as string in the dynamic column

```
INSERT INTO 
            your_table (dynamic_column) 
VALUES      
            (COLUMN_CREATE('myfield','value1'
                          ,'myList','["item1" , "item2", "item3"]') 
            );
```

OR

```
UPDATE 
        your_table
    SET
        dynamic_column = COLUMN_CREATE('myfield','value1'
                                      ,'myList','["item1" , "item2", "item3"]'
                                      )
    WHERE 
            id = your_id ;
```

So far so good now there's the tricky part. How you will return that without breaking the format. Using a replace function:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_JSON(dynamic_column),'"[','['),']"',']') FROM your_table ;
```

You also can test the output quickly without creating any table.

```
SET @tmp= COLUMN_CREATE('myfield','value1','myList','[ "item1"  , "item2" , "item3" ]' ) ;

 SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_JSON(@tmp),'"[','['),']"',']') json_string;
```

If it outputs breaking the json format with '\' :

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_string                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"myList":[ \"item1\"  , \"item2\" , \"item3\" ],"myfield":"value1"} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

then try something like

```
 SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_JSON(@tmp),'"[','['),']"',']'),'\\','') json_string;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_string                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"myList":[ "item1"  , "item2" , "item3" ],"myfield":"value1"} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**GIVE IT A GO !!**

** *Don't forget to validate the json string output on any online validator or text editor like textwrangler or notepad++*

** *Beware sometimes dynamic columns can be a dynamic pain*

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

CAST can be replaced with 
    JSON_MERGE('{"key": "val"}', JSON_OBJECT());